# Improper to reference MultiIndex values of DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Pandas seems to resist efforts to use DataFrame index values as if they are column values.  As a result I am often copying them into a column so that I can reference them for calculations.  Is this a good practice?  Or am I missing a "correct" way to reference index values?

Consider the following example:

```
j = [(a, b) for a in ['A','B','C'] for b in random.sample(range(1, 100), 5)]
i = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(j, names=['Name','Num'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(15), i, columns=['Vals'])
```

Now suppose I want to add a column `'SmallestNum'` to the DataFrame that lists the smallest index `Num` for each associated index `Name`.

Presently the only way I can find to get this to work (assuming that the MultiIndex is large and I don't have it handy as tuples) is to:

First: Copy both index levels into columns of the DataFrame:

```
df['NameCol'] = df.index.get_level_values(0)
df['NumCol'] = df.index.get_level_values(1)
```

Otherwise, I can't figure out how I would get the smallest `Num` value for each `Name`.  At least now I can via:

```
smallest = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Name'])['NumCol'].min())
```

Finally, I can merge these data back into the DataFrame as a new column, but only because I can reference the `NameCol`:

```
df.merge(smallest.rename(columns={'NumCol' : 'SmallestNum'}), how='left', right_index=True, left_on=['NameCol'])
```

So is there a way to do this without creating the `NameCol` and `NumCol` column copies of the MultiIndex values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
## get smallest values per Name
vals = df.reset_index(level=1).groupby('Name')['Num'].min()

## map the values to df
df['SmallestNum'] = pd.Series(df.index.get_level_values(0)).map(vals).values
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
np.random.seed(456) 

j = [(a, b) for a in ['A','B','C'] for b in np.random.randint(1, 100, size=5)]
i = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(j, names=['Name','Num'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(15), i, columns=['Vals'])
print (df)

              Vals
Name Num          
A    28   1.180140
     44   0.984257
     90   1.835646
     43  -1.886823
     29   0.424763
B    80  -0.433105
     61  -0.166838
     46   0.754634
     38   1.966975
     93   0.200671
C    40   0.742752
     82  -1.264271
     12  -0.112787
     78   0.667358
     70   0.357900
```

---

```
df['SmallestNum'] = df.reset_index(level=1).groupby('Name')['Num'].transform('min').values
```

Or:

```
df['SmallestNum'] = df.groupby('Name').transform(lambda x: x.index.get_level_values(1).min())
print (df)
              Vals  SmallestNum
Name Num                       
A    28   1.180140           28
     44   0.984257           28
     90   1.835646           28
     43  -1.886823           28
     29   0.424763           28
B    80  -0.433105           38
     61  -0.166838           38
     46   0.754634           38
     38   1.966975           38
     93   0.200671           38
C    40   0.742752           12
     82  -1.264271           12
     12  -0.112787           12
     78   0.667358           12
     70   0.357900           12
```